# Handling the event in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions for push notifications

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I was trying to send a json payload to my app with the following format,

```
    {"aps":
    {"alert":"Enquiry id =4. 
Push Notification from App Thu-Sep-2013 05:25:44",
"sound":"default","badge":1},"enquiryid":"4"
   }
```

I was eager to get the value of enquiryid in my app I was trying to do that with the following code.

```
NSDictionary *tmpDic = [launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];


if (tmpDic != nil) {
    NSString *temp = [tmpDic  objectForKey:@"enquiryid"];
    typeOfUser = @"enquiry";
}
```

However I am not able to get the value. I am in adhoc mode so I am not able to use `NSLog`.

Comment: I think this method is not calling when you are clicking on the PushNotification. Check it by adding the UIAlertView in the code.

Comment: didfinishlaunchingwithoptions method will definitely be called cause I am starting the app by tapping on push notification.

Comment: There are two conditions if your app is in background mode then didfinishlaunchingwithoptions won't call. If the app is not in background mode then only didfinishlaunchingwithoptions method will be called .

Comment: Try to confirm whether you app didfinishlaunchingwithoptions method calling by adding the UIAlertView in the method

Comment: No, my app is not in background mode....its not running..

Comment: Did you checked whether your app push notification is calling the method didfinishlaunchingwithoptions by adding the UIAlerView in the didfinishlaunchingwithoptions method?

Comment: yeah its calling the method..could you please let me know what should be my procedure to get that value in didfinishlaunchingwithoptions(any other method apart from mine)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37658/discussion-between-tendulkar-and-saty)